# Retrieve the date only if is not in past

Tags: excel, date

In cell A1, A2, A3, A4 i have the following dates:

```
A1: 01.01.2016
A2: 01.02.2016
A3: 01.03.2016
A4: 01.04.2016
```

in C1 I would like to show the date which is the closest to the current date but not in the past.

i.e. today 04.01.2016: C1 : 01.02.2016

if today 01.02.2016  C1: 01.02.2016
if today 02.02.2016  C1: 01.03.2016

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Enter with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

```
=MIN(IF(A1:A4-TODAY()>=0,A1:A4))
```

Answer (score 0):

For all intents and purposes, you are looking for a pseudo-MINIF function.

Use the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) with **15** as the [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) sub-function, discard errors with **6**, and use **1** as the *k* parameter to get the smallest (aka minimum).

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, A1:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,A:A ))/(A1:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,A:A ))>=TODAY()), 1)
```

[image: minif_aggregate]

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>